# When can partial spectral sparsifiers be combined?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

A few important papers about spectral sparsifiers and friends contain a technical idea that involves building many different sparsifiers that each "partially" solve the problem, and then combining them at the end.  To give two examples:

- The [original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.4134) by Spielman and Teng works roughly by partitioning the graph into parts of good expansion and $\le |E|/2$ edges going between the parts, then building a sparsifier of each part, and then recursing on the "remainder" graph to depth $\log n$ to get the rest.  Implicitly, one then combines these partial solutions at the end for a full solution.
- [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.00571.pdf) by Jambulapati and Sidford builds spectral sketches, which are data structures (not subgraphs) that can approximate Laplacian quadratic forms $x^T L x$ with probability $\ge 2/3$ for any given $x$.  As they mention, one can easily amplify this probability to $p$ by computing $\log (1/p)$ sketches and taking their median.  This critically uses that they sketch with data structures, not graphs, and it raises the question of whether a similar probability amplification is possible for *subgraphs* with this property.

Formalizing the question, let $G = (V, E, w)$ be a graph and let $H_1, H_2$ be reweighted subgraphs such that, for some $X_1, X_2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ we have
$$x^T L_{H_i} x \in (1 \pm \varepsilon) x^T L_G x \qquad \text{for all } x \in X_i.$$

> - I imagine that this does *not* imply generally that one can reweight $H_1 \cup H_2$ so that the above equation holds for all $x \in X_1 \cup X_2$.
>     Is this accurate, and is there a nice example that demonstrates this?
> - Are there natural additional assumptions we can make about $G, H_1, H_2$ so that this combination of $H_1, H_2$ does work in general, e.g. to enable recursive computation techniques like in the first paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your 1st question: no, this would not hold in general.

Rather (answering your 2nd question), the right way to interpret the approach by Spielman and Teng is as follows: let $G'$ be a vertex-induced subgraph of $G$, and $H'$ a spectral sparsifier of $G'$. Then the graph $G-G'+H'$ (replace all edges in $G'$ by those in $H'$) will be a spectral sparsifier of $G$. This easily follows by combining the Laplacians of $G$ and $H'$. As a result, we can sparsify $G$ by subsequently sparsifying subgraphs.

And finally, you are asking about ways to amplify the success probability of a sparsification algorithm. For spectral sparsification, there is a rather easy way: construct one with constant success probability, check whether it is indeed a spectral sparsifier (this amounts to checking whether a certain matrix is PSD, which can be done efficiently), if not, reiterate. After $O(\log(1/\epsilon))$ iteration this outputs a spectral sparsifier with probability at least $1-\epsilon$. Note that this cannot be done for say cut sparsification, as there is no efficient "verification procedure" to check whether a graph is a cut sparsifier of another graph.

Comment: Thanks for the response and for the clarification on the Spielman and Teng paper, very helpful.  For the last point: the model is that the subgraph has $x^T L_H x \approx x^T L_G x$ with constant probability *for any given $x$*.  What you are describing would work if there was constant probability that it holds *for all $x$ simultaneously,* which is stronger.

Comment: Oh, I see now that the question was about *sketches*, not sparsifiers. I guess you can easily restrict the input graph to a subgraph, so that's probably not your question.